# Random weighted distribution

Tags: php, probability, combinatorics, bernoulli-probability

For example I have an array like:

```
$items = [
    '0' => [
        'name' => 'item1', 
        'percent' => 10
        ],
    '2' => [
        'name' => 'item2', 
        'percent' => 20
        ],
    '3' => [
        'name' => 'item3', 
        'percent' => 30
        ],
    '4' => [
        'name' => 'item4', 
        'percent' => 40
        ],
];
```

And function:

```
function echoRandomItem(){
}
```

If I call this function it should return `'name'` of the item depending on the `'percent'` value. Basically if I call this function 100 times it should return `item1` 10 times, `item2` 20 times, `item3` 30 times, `item4` 40 times.

Comment: Hello, we're not developers for hire. Try to make this yourself, then if you have bugs in it, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Hey man, I cannot figure out the algorithm itself and want some help to figure it out. Maybe you know some formula that may help? At first sight the task seems easy, but I cannot grasp it.

Comment: It's called "random weighted distribution". Look for that on the Internet with the language you're using. By the way you've not even said which language you're using.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is my first time here so thank you for bearing with me. By the way it's PHP

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I've come up with thanks to Oliver's hint. `$items` is a given array. `wrand()` function is responsible for random weighted distribution calculation.

```
$items = [
    '1' => [
        'name' => 'item1', 
        'rand' => 10
        ],
    '2' => [
        'name' => 'item2', 
        'rand' => 20
        ],
    '3' => [
        'name' => 'item3', 
        'rand' => 30
        ],
    '4' => [
        'name' => 'item4', 
        'rand' => 40
        ],
];

function wrand($data) {

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $itemsRand[] = $value ['rand'];
    }

    $totalw = array_sum($itemsRand);
    $rand   = rand(1, $totalw);

    $curw   = 0;
    foreach ($data as $val) {
        $curw += $val['rand'];
        if ($curw >= $rand) return $val['name'];
    }

    return end($data);
}
```

Further code simply calls `wrand()` function 100 times and counts the results.

```
static $item1 = 0;
static $item2 = 0;
static $item3 = 0;
static $item4 = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    $k = wrand($items);

    if ($k == 'item1') {
        $item1++;
    } elseif ($k == 'item2'){
        $item2++;
    } elseif ($k == 'item3'){
        $item3++;
    } elseif ($k == 'item4'){
        $item4++;
    }
}

echo "item1 = $item1<br>";
echo "item2 = $item2<br>";
echo "item3 = $item3<br>";
echo "item4 = $item4";
```